# log4net only works on one project in multiple project solultion

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a multiple project solution which is using Log4Net for the logging. Log4Net is set up to log to a file and database. The file logging portion is working as expected. The database portion is only working for one project.

```
namespace Solution.ProjectOne
{
     class A
     {
         private ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(A));

         public A()
         {
             log4net.config.XmlConfigurator();
         }

         public void AMethod()
         {
             log.Info("I work"); // Works
         }

         public B LoadB()
         {
             // B is loaded via reflection in our solution
             return new B();
         }
     }

}

namespace solution.ProjectTwo
{   
    class B
    {
        private ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(B));

        public B()
        {}

        public void BMethod()
        {
            // This logs to the file but not the database.
            log.Error("I do not work"); 
        }
    }
}   



<log4net>
    <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">

      <bufferSize value="100" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data,     Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="server=<SERVER>;database=<DATABASE>; UID=<USERNAME>;Password=<PASSWORD>;Enlist=false; Connect Timeout=60; Max Pool Size=100" />
      <commandText value="dbo.SP_SaveLog" />
      <commandType value="StoredProcedure" /> 
      <parameter>

        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date{yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff}" />
      </parameter>
      - <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%thread" />
      </parameter>
      - <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%level" />
      </parameter>
      - <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%logger" />
      </parameter>
      - <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%message" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="WARN"/>
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="debug" />
      <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: are all your project configured as the one that is actually working? because i see some missing parameters in what you copied

Comment: @sdmon They are all running from the same configuration file. What is missing? It is always possible that I missed something and the missing parameters are the issue. Thanks

Comment: _"B is loaded via reflection in our solution"_ that looks like a clue. Are you loading the assembly?

Comment: Have you tried enabling internal debugging for log4net? Also are you sure this is the log4net configuration file that you are using, (because I would have expected the rollingFileAppender section to include the name/location of the log file)? However it is strange that you say the file logging works from both projects but not the database.

Comment: Oh ok, you MUST configure log4net in every project, the thing is, if you use 1 logging class you import that class... but it will use the configuration of that project where you try to use it, so all configuration must be the same in all your projects